# can't get local file to save into database using Rails 3 and paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, file-upload, paperclip

I have an Image model that has an attached file :photo and am attempting to save a local file into photo using the console.

My Image model:

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_attached_file :photo
 attr_accessor :photo_file_name
 belongs_to :item
end
```

My Image migrations:

```
class CreateImages < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
   create_table :images do |t|
   t.string :photo_file_name
   t.string :photo_content_type
   t.integer :photo_file_size
   t.datetime :photo_updated_at
   t.timestamps
 end
end

def self.down
 drop_table :images
end
end
```

At the console:

```
a=Image.new
 => #<Image id: nil, file_name: nil, content_type: nil, file_size: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, item_id: nil> 

a.photo=File.new('/home/bobloblaw/Pictures/nomnom.jpg')
 => #<File:/home/bobloblaw/Pictures/nomnom.jpg> 

a.save
 => true 

a.photo
 => /system/photos/2/original/nomnom.jpg?1302065614 

Image.first.photo
 => /photos/original/missing.png
```

So, as you can see, a.photo contains the correct information, but somehow is not correctly saving it into Image in the actual database.  I have also tried various combinations of adding things such as :photo and :photo_file_name to attr_accessible.

Any help would be appreciated as I've searched all over at haven't found anyone else with this problem!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just replace

```
attr_accessor :photo_file_name
```

to

```
attr_accessor :photo
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure `Image.first` is returning this record that you just created. Double check that it contains the correct `photo_*` fields.

Comment: I double checked and there is only one record and Image.first is the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

you have to give the :url and :path..

like this

has_attached_file :accountlogo,

```
                :storage => :s3,
                :s3_credentials => "#{RAILS_ROOT}/config/amazon_s3.yml",
                :url  => "/accountslogo/:id/:basename.:extension",
                :path => "/accountslogo/:id/:basename.:extension"
                # :path => ":rails_root/public/accountslogo/:id/:basename.:extension"
```

Comment: I tried this but with no success.  It does the same thing with and without adding the :url and :path.  I also notice that it is copying the file into the correct directory.  For whatever reason it's just not saving .photo in the actual database.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing from your model definition. This accessor will be created automatically.

```
attr_accessor :photo_file_name
```

Answer (score 0):

Give `File.read`, not `File.new` a try.